# Есть ли нулевое окончание в слове ЧТО-ЛИБО?

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Согласно словарю Зализняка местоимение-существительное *что-либо* является склоняемым (по образцу слова *что*), а следовательно, по аналогии со схемой членения на морфемы других изменяемых слов в нём должно выделяться окончание, возможно нулевое. Верно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Есть ли нулевое окончание в слове ***что-либо?***

В местоименных существительных ***что*** и ***что-либо*** нет нулевого окончания, но есть флексия ***О***.

АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР
ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА
РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА

**ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫЕ
МЕСТОИМЕНИЯ-СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ**

[**§ 1287.**](https://rusgram.narod.ru/1270-1293.html) Местоимения кто и что не имеют падежных форм **мн. ч.** Все падежные формы, кроме формы им. п. у местоимения кто и формы им. и вин. п. у местоимения что, образуются по второй разновидности местоименного скл. (см. § 1325). В формах им. п. (кто) и им. и вин. п. (что) выступает **флексия -|о|.** У местоимения **кто** формы род. и вин. п. ед. ч. совпадают; у местоимения **что** совпадают формы им. и вин. п.

Падежные формы местоимений **кто и что** образуются от основ |**кт|**-, **|чт|**- (формы им. п.) и **|к|-**, **|к'|**- и **|ч|-** (формы косв. пад.): кт-о, чт-о, но к-ого, ч-его, к-ому, ч-ему, к-ем, ч-ем.

Парадигмы

```
 И. кт-о    чт-о
 Р. к-ого   ч-его
 Д. к-ому   ч-ему
 В. к-ого   чт-о
Тв. к-ем    ч-ем
Пр. о к-ом  о ч-ём
```

В форме тв. п. мест. кто имеет место позиционное смягчение: |к'ем|.

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО**

**§ 1285.** Вопросительные местоимения **кто и что** обозначают **вопрос** об одушевленном (кто) или о неодушевленном предмете (что). Эти местоимения не имеют морфологической категории **рода**. Местоимение кто синтаксически ведет себя **как сущ. муж.** р.: кто пришел?; кто из девочек ушел?; кто изображен на этом женском портрете?; А если кто для меня непонятен, так это моя бабушка графиня Анна Федотовна (Пушк.). **Местоимение что** синтаксически ведет себя как сущ. сред. р.: что случилось?; что произошло?

Местоимение **что** может указывать на лицо в тех случаях, когда целью вопроса является установление не личности человека

**§ 1286**. Местоимения кто и что не имеют морфологической категории **числа**. Противопоставление по числу выражается только у слова **кто** и только **синтаксически** – формами согласуемого определения или, реже, глагола-сказуемого. На число, ед. или мн., часто указывает форма прилагательного такой: кто такой (такая)? и кто такие?: А ты кто такой, – сказал Шабашкин с дерзким взором (Пушк.); [Баев:] А эти кто такие? (Булг.). Местоимение **что** не выражает противопоставления по числу и всегда имеет значение **единичности:** что такое?; что происходит?; что произошло?

Местоимения **кто и что** употребляются также как относительные слова в составе сложного предложения. Выполняя функцию союзного слова (см. § 1685), слова кто и что сохраняют грамматические особенности **местоимений-существительных:** они изменяются **по падежам,** а в тех случаях, когда выступают в роли подлежащего, **координируются со сказуемым в роде и числе**. При этом, когда речь идет о многих, нормой является употребление сказуемого – глагола, прилагательного или причастия в форме **ед. ч**. Форма **мн. ч.** здесь возможна в не строго нормированной речи: кто едет! (едут), должны, прийти к восьми утра; все, кто внесен в список/(внесены в список), приняты. В том случае, когда сказуемое выражено прилагательным, причастием или глаголом в форме прош. вр. или сослагат. накл., нормально употребление этих слов при местоимении кто в форме муж. р., а при местоимении что – в форме сред. р.: кто это видел, тот не забудет; что сделано, то сделано.

**[Статья по теме](https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200202206)**  С.ЕВГРАФОВА. Маргинальная лингвистика на вступительных экзаменах. (Заметки о местоимениях.)