# Трудное предложение: грамматика и знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, тире, интонация

*Петух — **не соловей и в довоенное время пел на рассвете.***

По семантике это ***ССП*** (два сообщения), но как объяснить отсутствие **запятой** перед союзом ***И***? Может, нужно другое понимание **грамматики**?  И как прочитать предложение с правильной **интонацией**?

Другими словами, как объяснить предложение, чтобы было полное соответствие (семантика, грамматика, интонация, знаки, правила)?

https://yandex.ru/video/preview/3516521978429028884

```
В десять часов вечера под Светлое Воскресенье утих 
наш проклятый коридор. В блаженной тишине родилась у 
меня жгучая мысль о том, что исполнилось мое 
мечтанье и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, 
умерла. Решил это я  потому, что из комнаты Павловны 
не доносилось криков истязуемого ее сына Шурки.
Я сладострастно улыбнулся, сел в драное кресло и 
развернул томик Марка Твена. О, миг блаженный, 
светлый час!..
…И в десять с четвертью вечера в коридоре трижды 
пропел петух.Петух — ничего особенного. Ведь жил же 
у Павловны полгода поросенок в комнате. Вообще 
Москва не Берлин, это раз, а во-вторых, человека, 
живущего полтора года в коридоре No 50, не удивишь 
ничем. Не факт  неожиданного появления петуха 
испугал меня, а то обстоятельство, что петух пел в 
десять часов вечера. Петух — не соловей и в 
довоенное время пел на рассвете. (Михаил Булгаков. 
"Самогонное озеро".)
```

Comment: Считалось, видимо, что *петух — не соловей* нужно принимать как подлежащее. Тире хорошо бы заменить ни дефис, но НЕ мешает, хотя вот в НК встретился вариант вовсе без «лишних» знаков: «...он не барин и помочь этим людям ничем не может».

Comment: Без тире можно обойтись, но почему  запятой нет в ССП. Или это однородные сказуемые? Как-то однородность в них не чувствуется, совершенно разные признаки (прич.-следств. отношения).

Comment: @shampar, о каком дефисе здесь может идти речь?! К тому же нельзя вмешиваться в авторский текст. Тут только тире.

Comment: Так же, как и желать *прочитать предложение с правильной интонацией*. Разбирать текст не значит вмешиваться.

Comment: Вы предлагаете заменить тире на дефис, а это вмешательство уже.

Comment: Да, звукозаписей рассказа Булгакова нет, вероятно. https://textarchive.ru/c-1319439-p15.html   Остается   вариант правильной реконструкции. Но ведь у нас почти вся историческая грамматика реконструирована))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный пример — простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми. Об этом свидетельствует один и тот субъект. Хотя нужно признать,что вопрос об однородных сказуемых является спорным. Что касается причинно-следственных отношениях, то такие отношения возможны и между однородными сказуемыми. Да и причинно-следственные отношения здесь не главные.
https://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik-scibook/prichinno-sledstvennyie-otnosheniya-36834.html

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, голос от меня. Всё бы хорошо, кроме интонации. При наличии тире корректное прочтение невозможно.  Можно так: Петух не соловей и в довоенное время пел на рассвете.  Или так: Петух — не соловей, и в довоенное время пел на рассвете.   Что мешает поставить запятую? // У меня ваши ссылки не открываются,  к сожалению.

Comment: Кстати, про что-либо вы не могли что-нибудь сказать? Какое мнение о склонении местоимений в современной науке, что-нибудь изменилось? А то наши участники такие темы аккуратно проходят мимо.  За вопрос голоса поставили, но это давно было. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460724/Есть-ли-нулевое-окончание-в-слове-ЧТО-ЛИБО

Comment: Тире интонационное. Что касается ссылки, даже не знаю, что делать. У меня ссылка открывается.

Comment: Интонационное тире должно соответствовать интонации, а не противоречить ей.  Сравнить: Петух не соловей /  и в довоенное время пел на рассвете.  Это нормально. А у вас две паузы на простое предложение.   Это  уже ненормально.// А без ссылки вы не могли бы пару слов сказать, о чем речь, что за тема?

Comment: Наберите в Гугле причинно-следственные отношения при однородных сказуемых. Выберите сайт sci.house.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.  Я не возражаю против однородности сазуемых, но тогда там тире лишнее. Убирайте тире)

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. Я не возражаю против однородности сказуемых, но тогда там тире лишнее.  Будем считать, что это авторское графическое оформление.

Comment: Что касается местоимения, вы и сами прекрасно дали ответ на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагается такое решение.

**ФАНТАЗИЯ на тему синтаксической синонимии** для конкретной семантики:

***Петух — (он) не соловей И в довоенное время (он) пел на рассвете.***

***Петух*** — именительный темы, после него пауза и тире. А дальше ССП (сложносочиненное предложение), союз ***И*** при наличии **общего элемента** в лице "именительного" петуха.

Тогда запятая не ставится, прочтение двух простых предложений без паузы (в одну фонетическую фразу).

Comment: Интересно, за что поставили минус вам?

Comment: Мне обычно минус ставят ни за что))  Я даже не заметила.